# Why do the buttons in my Reanimated Bottom Sheet work in some places, but not others on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I have a RN/Expo App with a Reanimated Bottom Sheet. The bottom sheet has buttons in it that work fine on iOS, regardless of the screen's orientation, but only work some of the time on Android, depending on screen orientation.

I have replicated the issue in a Snack,[here.](https://snack.expo.dev/@mk_pierce3450/fcd3d2)

I believe it may be related to my StyleSheet, but I don't know for sure.